# No non-trivial homomorphism to a group

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Hausdorff topological group, and let $H$ be a torsion-free group satisfying the ascending condition, i.e. there are no infinite strictly ascending chains $H_1<H_2<...$ of subgroups of $H.$

> Prove that there is no non-trivial homomorphism of $G$ into $H.$

Note: no topology is considered on $H$ and "homomorphism" simply means "group homomorphism."

Comment: A somewhat related question was asked and [answered on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80966/), recently. I haven't looked at the paper mentioned in the answer, but maybe it contains something useful for this question.

Comment: @t.b:The given thread solves the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Ehsanmo, could you then answer your own question and accept the answer so this question doesn't show up in unanswered questions? Thank you.

Comment: @ymar: Yes, sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that such an $H$ is finitely generated and the rest follows from [Nikolov-Segal theorem.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80966/)

I wonder if there is a non high-tech way to prove it though!

Comment: Yes there's a non-hightech way: pick by contradiction $g$ not in the kernel of such a homomorphism $f$: then we can replace $G$ by the closure $G_1$ of the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$, and $H$ by its image $f(G_1)$. Then $G_1$ is abelian, and hence so is $H_1$. Since $H$ is torsion-free and noetherian, $H_1$ is a (nontrivial) finitely generated torsion-free abelian group. Replacing $H_1$ by a quotient reduces to $H_1=\mathbf{Z}$. One concludes, for instance as in https://mathoverflow.net/a/194613/14094 The Nikolov-Segal theorem allows not to use the assumption torsion-free noetherian.